# How to update an SQLite database replacing roolback journal by shadow paging

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

Sqlite is the native database for android devices which work on flash memory. Rollback journal uses update-in-place technique. Since, limited no of write operation can be done on a particular data segment of flash drives, before it be come unusable, shadow paging (update-out-of-place) can increase the life the the flash drives.

Since, size of the page in sqlite is small, shadow paging can be an better alternative for rollback journal. Shadow paging can increase the speed of execution of these apps, which is the important think any one is looking in smart phones or tablet.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to decide to use a different transaction implementation at runtime. The implementation of transactions and rollbacks belong the inner parts of a database. Therefore I guess, to change the inner parts, you have to implement the shadow paging by yourself. Also, I never heard that the write operations of sqlite lead to unusable flash drives. Furthermore, why does shadow paging increase the speed of executing apps?

Comment: I am aware of the fact that for implementing shadow paging, I have to modify inner part of sqlite.
It is not the sqlite write operation that leads to unsable flash drives, its the property of flash drives that limited no of write operation can be done on it.
Since of updating any page sqlite first create a rollback jouranl which written to secondary memory before actual update takes place.

Comment: Instead in shadow paging only file pointers are needed to be updated makes it work faster the journal.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, the mechanism most similar to shadow paging is called [write-ahead logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html); enable it by executing `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`.

The difference from shadow paging is that the pages are logically modified in place (physically, they are written to the log instead), and that from time to time those modified pages are merged back into the actual database (called [checkpointing](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt)).

Comment: @CL- You are right, but still WAL is in-place update and that does not solve the problem of unusable data segments in flash drives.

Comment: Updates are written to the log, not in place.